# lmer, glmer, and r squared

Tags: lme4-nlme

Seems like I got really confused, so here I am...

I'm trying to fit lmer model with a quite simple dataset -

- Observation.count as a dependent variable - count of observations for a student within a course,
- condition (graded/not_graded), and experience (yes/no) as fixed
  effects (and interaction between condition and experience), and
- total annotation count and student within a course as random effects.

I tried to fit 3 models:

- null model with random effects only - 1|ann_count + 1|stud_id (no nesting yet)
- fixed model - added fixed effects
- full model - added nesting 1|ann_count + 1|class_name/stud_id

Since I wasn't able to fit the full model with lmer (similar to the problem describer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662870/explanation-for-error-with-lmer-but-not-glmer-error-in-checknlevelsretrmsflis), I used glmer with Poisson distribution. Calculating r squared as describer here http://jonlefcheck.net/2013/03/13/r2-for-linear-mixed-effects-models/ (thanks Jon), resulted in the following:

```
NULL MODEL:
     Class  Family   Link Marginal Conditional      AIC
  glmerMod  poisson  log        0   0.9453669     761.1058


FIXED MODEL:
   Class  Family  Link  Marginal    Conditional      AIC
glmerMod poisson  log   0.2450208   0.9289952       738.1011

FULL MODEL:
   Class  Family  Link  Marginal    Conditional     AIC
glmerMod poisson  log   0.2792817    0.907318       722.278
```

According to AIC and AICc the full model seems to be the best fit, but what about r squared?
Also, if relevant, with lmer I got this:

```
NULL MODEL:
         Class   Family    Link Marginal Conditional      AIC
merModLmerTest gaussian identity        0   0.5771834 817.7468

FIXED MODEL:

         Class   Family     Link  Marginal   Conditional    AIC
merModLmerTest gaussian identity  0.3954737   0.5365684    780.86
```

Any comments/ideas/suggestions on what to do, which model/approach to use would be much appreciated...

Comment: Can you describe the response a little more?

Comment: @LaurenGoodwin you mean Observation.count? That is just a count variable that says how many observations student had within a course.

Comment: I guess the reason I am asking is due to using the Poisson model. Is a Poisson model even appropriate, so I am trying to understand what these counts are.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenGoodwin. There is a long story behind those observations, but basically it's about new coding scheme that we are proposing. Students are supposed to watch a video and say how many "observations" there was (this is fairly simplified version of it). This count represents all the observations they identified within a single course. Does that make sense?